In VSCode language extension while comment toggling, comment indicator goes to 1 column left side from cursor pointer
I am creating a language extension, we don't use 1st column in this language purposely. So My language code start from 2nd column only. Now when I comment using "CTRL+/" (comment toggling) language code statement, Comment indicator (!) goes to first column (which is invalid in my language), my code shift by 1 column to right side.
I have to explicitly move comment indicator to 2nd column. then only comments are recognised by Textmate grammar. Please checkout the below image.

Is there a way to configure such thing in vscode language extension.

an you make your line comments to be  ! (with a leading space)?

VSCode adds comments after the last indentation whitespace.
So changing your Tab Size to 1 would fix it.
package.json:
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
        "[languageId]": {
            "editor.tabSize": 1
        }
    }
}

OR you could add a space   to "lineComment": " !".
But it'll prob have problems with uncommenting, if the existing comment doesn't have a space before it.
